# Formatting toString Java

Tags: java, format, tostring

I'd like to know how to format `toString`:
I tried using `printf` and s`tring.format` but it wants me to change `String` and `int` to `Object[]`

I want it to look like this: (Spaces)

> Book1______Author1________850
>
> Book23_____Author2424_____250

```
class Book
{
    private String title,author;
    private int numberOfPages;

    Book()
    {

    }

    public Book(String title, String author, int pages) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.numberOfPages = pages;
    }

    public String toString()   
    {
        return(title + "%63s") + "\t" + (author + "%63s") + "\t" + numberOfPages;
        // It actually works but makes the "%63s" appear :o
    }
}
```

Comment: `%63s` is just a string literal that you concatenate. The tabs are added by `"\t"`, so you could simply remove the `%63s`, but this will most likely not align if your book titles and, or, authors are of different lengths. Edit: Are you trying to get a collection of books aligned? If so, you cannot do this for individual toString methods.

Comment: You _should_ be using `String.format`.  What's the issue?

Comment: "The method format(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, int)"

:(

Answer (score 6):

```
return String.format("%-30s%-30s%10d", title, author, numberOfPages);
```

Comment: I tried that already, it says:
"The method format(Locale, String, Object[]) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (String, String, String, int)"  :/

Comment: @user3764862 What version of Java are you using?

Answer (score 2):

String.format is correct.  You just need to get the formatting string correct.

Update your `toString()` method as follows:

```
public String toString()   
{
    return String.format("%63s\t%63s\t%10d", title, author, numberOfPages);
}
```

The first `%63s` will be replaced with `title`.

The `%63s` will be replaced with `author` and add spaces to make it 63 characters past the end of the title.

The `%10d` will be replaced with `numberOfPages` and pad the number out to 10 digits wide.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if you want to align the titles, the authors and the number of pages in three separate columns. But if you do with to do this, you cannot achieve this by overriding the `toString` method of Book, because it will not know how long the title and author names of the other books in the collection are.

You can, however, declare a custom collection for your books and override its `toString` method. This could look as follows:

```
class Main {

static class Book
{
    private String title,author;
    private int numberOfPages;

    public Book(String title,String author,int pages) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.numberOfPages = pages;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return String.format("%-30s%-30s%10d", title, author, numberOfPages);
    }

}

static class Library {

    public static final int Margin = 2;

    private List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
    public void addBook(Book book){
        books.add(book);
    }
    private int longestTitle() {
        int result = 0;
        for (Book book : books) {
            result = book.title.length() > result ? book.title.length() : result;
        }
        return result;
    }
    private int longestAuthor() {
        int result = 0;
        for (Book book : books) {
            result = book.author.length() > result ? book.author.length() : result;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String result = "";
        for (Book book : books) {
            int titleLength = book.title.length();
            result += book.title;
            for (int i = longestTitle(); i > titleLength - Margin; i--){
                result += " ";
            }
            result += book.author;
            int authorLength = book.author.length();
            for (int i = longestAuthor(); i > authorLength - Margin; i--){
                result += " ";
            }
            result += book.numberOfPages + "\n";
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Library lib = new Library();
    Book b1 = new Book("Knights of the round table", "King Arthur", 123);

    lib.addBook(b1);
    Book b2 = new Book("It", "Stephen King", 1345);
    lib.addBook(b2);
    Book b3 = new Book("A very, very, very, very long title that seems pointless", "Me", 112);
    lib.addBook(b3); 
//  System.out.println(b1);
//  System.out.println(b2);
//  System.out.println(b3);
//  They do not align separately
    System.out.println(lib.toString());
}

}
```

The idea is to look which title is the longest and add for each book you want to print a padding that reaches at least the longest title. The same for the author.

Note that this code isn't written really well, but it should suffice to convey the idea.